# Preserving Page State in Silverlight (like IProvideCustomContentState)

Tags: .net, silverlight, browser-history, deep-linking

Is there any way to store a Silverlight page's state in the browser's history as with [IProvideCustomContentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.iprovidecustomcontentstate.aspx) (a WPF class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried NavigationCacheMode="Required"?